# couldn't Install TensorFlow Python dependencies

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

I am installing tensorFlow from source by following the instructions mentioned in Tensorflow website. when I install TensorFlow Python dependencies using the command `sudo yum install python3-numpy python3-dev python3-pip python3-wheel` it gives me this error

```
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ventraip.net.au
 * epel: epel.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 * extras: mirror.ventraip.net.au
 * updates: mirror.intergrid.com.au
No package python3-numpy available.
No package python3-dev available.
No package python3-pip available.
No package python3-wheel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I checked the python version using the command  `python --version` it shows Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)`and my operating system is CentOS Linux 7 (Core). I am new to Linux and Tensorflow.

Thank you

Comment: yes since I am using centOS instead of using apt-get I used yum

Comment: You can install tensorflow using conda. Try this one; conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu(for GPU) or conda install -c anaconda tensorflow(for CPU)

Answer (score 0):

Try these instructions
https://edwards.sdsu.edu/research/installing-python3-4-and-the-scipy-stack-on-centos/

or you can install pip3 and install all the dependencies using pip3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install numpy
```